# Unable to get asp infro from flash

Tags: asp.net, actionscript-3, flash, asp-classic

I have to say I am having a heck of a time trying to get asp data into flash, looking through countless postings and forums, I am at a loss as to what I am doing wrong. I have a vb asp page with a simple response.write and flash code trying to pick up the variable. Its able to communicate with the page but what I'm getting is the whole .asp page that has been url encoded. Not sure why this is happening.

ASP:

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<%
response.Write("var1=info1")
%>
```

AS3:

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onDataSaved);
    loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;

    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("aspTest.asp");
    request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

    var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    request.data = variables;

    loader.load(request);


function onDataSaved(e:Event):void 
{
    var loader2:URLLoader = URLLoader(e.target);
    loader2.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
    trace(loader2.data["var1"]);//traces undefined
    trace(loader2.data);//gets the whole url encoded page.

}
```

after looking through a great number of other forums they suggesting stripping of the html tags which worked fine for others. But I can not for the life of me understand why this is not working. Please any help would be greatly appreciated, I have tried everything I could possibly think of and am at my wit's end on how to solve this. Thank you guys for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are almost there.

```
function onDataSaved(e:Event):void 
{
    var loader2:URLLoader = URLLoader(e.target);
    var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables(loader2.data);
    trace(variables.var1);
}
```

Comment: This worked! I can't thank you enough The_asMan, this has been a problem that has been going on for quite some time now. You are super awesome, seriously thank you!